# Dart/Flutter widget with optional parameters but at least one required

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I'm trying to create a Flutter widget that can be initialized by various parameters, something like this

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? id;
  final String? username;

  MyWidget({this.id, this.username});

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.id != null) {
      // init based on id
    } else if (widget.username != null) {
      // init based on username
    } else {
      // this should never happen
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(); // build some widget
  }
}
```

As you can see, neither of `id` and `username` are required, but I would need that at least one of them present. What would be a good way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  const TestWidget.name({this.id, @required this.name});
  const TestWidget.id({@required this.id, this.name});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(id ?? name),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can declare the constructor as anyone of these

```
  MyWidget(this.id,{this.username});//ID is required. Usage will be MyWidget(1,usename:'test');
  MyWidget(this.username,{this.id});//username is required Usage will be MyWidget('test',id:1);
  MyWidget({required this.id, this.username}); //id required
  MyWidget({this.id, required this.username});//username required
  MyWidget({requried this.id, required this.username});//both required
```

And you can also use [Assert Statement](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert) to check values at runtime have a look

```
MyWidget({this.id, this.username}):assert(id != null && username != null,'Both parameters cannot be null');
```